# Ruby on Rails devise - No route matches [GET] "/users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First time using devise I'm a little confused. I've followed a tutorial that manually goes through authentication so I have some understanding of Rails in this respect.

Normally when you create a scaffold for a User you get a Users controller with all the methods for showing, editing, adding etc. users, which can be accessed through the browser via `http://localhost:3000/users/[action]`.

I have destroyed the User scaffold and started again with devise (rails generate devise User) but this does not create a controller at all. Going to `http://localhost:3000/users/` gives the error `No route matches [GET] "/users"`.

Am I supposed to create my own controller? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Show your routes.rb. Looks like problem with routing (you need something like `resources :users` over there)

Comment: When I do add that, the error returned becomes `uninitialized constant UsersController`, so I am guessing I need to create my own UsersController? Can I copy and paste the default one generated by the scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not initialized devise. You should probably run

```
rails generate devise:install
```

And then generate model for User by running

```
rails generate devise User
```

Comment: I did because when I try that again there is a conflict. I could start over but I'm pretty sure I ran that since it was in the guide I followed for setting up devise.

Comment: Yep. I have made a brand new project and pasted these instructions in the terminal https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started